# LINQPad Vs. .NET Regex Performance Mismatch

Tags: c#, regex, linqpad

All, I have a series of SQL statements seperated in a `string` by 'GO' (case insensitive, so 'Go', 'go' et al. are also valid). If I have a statement like

```
string str = "INSERT INTO People \r\n" + 
                "VALUES (3, 'Gandalf', 'The Gray'); \r\nGO\r\n" + 
             "INSERT INTO People \r\n" + 
                "VALUES (4, 'Legolas', 'Camus'); \r\nGO";
```

I want to avoid a match on the 'go' in 'Legolas'. To do this I devised a regular expression in LINQPad with both *negative lookahead* and *positive lookbehind*, and have

```
string str = "INSERT INTO People \r\n" + 
                "VALUES (3, 'Gandalf', 'The Gray'); \r\nGO\r\n" + 
             "INSERT INTO People \r\n" + 
                "VALUES (4, 'Legolas', 'Camus'); \r\nGO";
Regex regGo = new Regex(@"(?<=\b)(?i)GO(?!\w+)");
MatchCollection matches = regGo.Matches(str);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    m.Dump();
}
```

Which does what I want, namely, it only matches a 'GO' (of any case) when it is a new 'GO' and not followed by anything. This works in LINQPad - i.e. returns the required result; but **not** in my C# app.

Why the descrepancy and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It would certainly help if you would tell us what the discrepancies are.

Comment: off the top of my head, have you checked the framework versions match between LP and VS?

Comment: Are you testing against the *exact same* statement in LINQPad as your real code has, or just one you think looks like it?

Comment: are the GO statements always on a separate line?

Comment: The GOs arn't always on a seperate line. This text comes from an editor which I then parse. Also, I AM yesting against the exact same statement. Thanks for your time...

Comment: Are you sure? If the script is to be executed by SSMS or SQLCMD, the GO statement must exist on a line of its own in order to be recognized. The only thing that can coexist is a comment to the right, and whitespace on either side. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: Hi @JoeAlbahari! Thanks very much for your reply. I looked in to this problem deeper an it was a very subtle bug in my C# application and not a decrepancy between the LINQPad/.NET performance. I apologise to waste you time here. I accepted the answer below as it was a reasonable suggestion, not because it was the resolution to my intial question. I hope you are well, all the best and thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your example to work in both LinqPad and a Console app.

A suggestion to simplify your regex and avoid using look behind and look ahead would be to use word boundaries like this:

> `\b(?i)GO\b`

This will accomplish the same result and be a little more readable.

Comment: This is confusing, I am really not sure why this is not working in my app. Thanks for your suggestion. It is a good one...

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Out of curiosity are you replacing the .Dump() extension method? I had to replace it in my Console app with Console.WriteLine(m.Value) to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah. I was also making another school boy error. But your suggestion was a good one and worthy of the Rep...

Comment: Watch out: this will also match INSERT INTO X VALUES ('GO'). It's difficult, if not impossible, to solve this with RegEx. LINQPad itself uses a full lexical parser to identify the 'GO' statement when running queries in SQL mode. Don't forget that the word 'GO' can also occur in comments (including multi-line comments).

Answer (score 0):

Just a small suggestion:

Use the following regex instead:

```
^GO$
```

It matches `GO` only when it is the first and last string in a line.

Comment: The Gos might be not the first and not the last in a string like in the example above...